# Iterated subplot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, pythonxy

Currently, I make a subplot (using `matplotlib`) with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
```

I want a variable number (n) of subplots in my plot named ax1, ax2, ... axn
So it should be something like

```
mylist = []
for num in xrange(n):
     mylist.append('ax'+str(num))
fig, (mylist) = plt.subplots(n, sharex=True)
```

However, this doesn't work because it just writes over "mylist" instead of using the names in the list.

Another solution would be if I didn't create the list and just used the names it creates for the axes, however, I do not know how to access these names.
If I try to access the names with

```
mylist[0]
```

The console says

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x09BFAEF0>
```

How can I use this number to plot with a line such as

```
 ax1.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create multiple axes:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3)
```

`axes` will be a numpy array containing the 3 axes objects.

In order to use them to plot you can index the array to access the axes objects and plot as you would normally (`ax.plot(...)`):

```
axes[0].plot(x, y)
```

If you have many axes then you can also loop through these axes and plot:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is create variables dyncamically. You can do that by using the following piece of code:

```
vars()[str_name_of_your_variable] = variable_assignment
```

However this is highly discouraged since it does not provide an efficient way of handling a variable number of data. It is better to store the assignments in a list or a dictionary:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n, sharex=True)
```

In `axes` you have all your axes, and you can select them by `axes[n]`. You can put that into a dictionary if you want.